# Подскажите что не так с парсером на python

Tags: python, парсер

Есть сайт https://polus.atom.online/quiz.php нужно спарсить текс из этого блока

```
`<div id="q-text" class="mt30 mobmt20 white sz16 lh22 atom400 h100p">
  "Один из первых аналогов такого устройства весил почти тонну и был размером с холодильник. 
  Что это за устройство?"
 </div>
```

Вот код парсера:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
url = 'https://polus.atom.online/quiz.php'
page = requests.get(url)
filteredNews = []
allNews = []
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html.parser")
allNews = soup.findAll('div', class_='mt30 mobmt20 white sz16 lh22 atom400 h100p')
print(allNews)
```

Вывод: `[<div class="mt30 mobmt20 white sz16 lh22 atom400 h100p" id="q-text"></div>]`
Почему выводится код блока но сам текс исчезает

Comment: потому что его там нет: https://i.imgur.com/sXpVh4t.png

Comment: я полагаю, что вы ищите что-то такое: https://i.imgur.com/b1waZJ8.png